# Visual Studio Window Shortcut Wonkyness

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've been diligently memorizing VS 2010 shortcuts based on the cheatsheats on Scott Guthries blog.

The shortcuts in the cheatsheet for WIndows dont match my setup e.g. Ctrl W,C is the cheatsheet shortcut to open the class viewer but mine is Ctrl + SHift, C. Maybe this is because my 08 settings got picked up at some point.

I've changed the shortcuts for viewing windows to match the cheat sheet (Ctrl + W,...) however most of the time Ctrl+W,... isn't working for me, whereas the previously defined shortcuts still work. If I go into the keyboard mappings I can see the shortcuts under global are Ctrl+W.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: wonkyness :D beautifully descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to *Tools -> Options -> General -> Keyboard*, focus the textbox labelled "Press shortcut keys" and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.  The dropdown list beneath it will show all corresponding actions.  Action mappings are contextual -- they depend on what has the focus.  Furthermore, 'Global' actions only apply if a more localised mapping does not exist.  Check for anything applied to 'Text Editor'.  If it exists and you don't want it, remove it by digging the action out in the 'Show commands containing' textbox above and clicking 'Remove'.

Also, do you have ReSharper installed?  I love R#, but it uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> so the series of shortcuts you're referring to aren't available without being remapped or changing the R# keystroke (which I wouldn't personally, as I use it all the time.)